# How to get message on LINE bot to local database with Python

Tags: python, heroku, github, line, webhooks

I already have a webhook URL from Heroku. That link is connected with github. I need to print the value of message and user id and put it on my local mysql. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: i allready post the picture

Comment: You probably want to add a data store to your heroku app https://elements.heroku.com/addons then use one of the data store utilities to export your data